# login is not function

Tags: angular, ionic4

when i open the login page and click on login button i get the problem that login is not a function i didnt understand whats the problem when i call the login function i get this error

> ERROR TypeError: "_co.login is not a function"

this is my **home.page.html**

```html
<ion-content padding center text-center>
<ion-img src="../assets/icon/logo.png" style="width:30%" class="pic"> 
</ion-img>
<ion-title class="titre">Pronto Book</ion-title>
<ion-list>
<ion-item style="width:89%;" class="useritem">
  <ion-input placeholder="Usuário" [(ngModel)]="username" type="email" 
class="user" autofocus></ion-input>
</ion-item>
<ion-item style="width:89%;" class="passitem">
  <ion-input placeholder="Senha" [(ngModel)]="password" type="password" 
class="pass" autofocus></ion-input>
</ion-item>
<button ion-button full class="but" (click)="login()">LOGIN</button>
 </ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

and this is the content of my **home.module.ts**

```js
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
import { IonicModule, NavController, NavParams } from '@ionic/angular';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { HomePage } from './home.page';
import { logging } from 'protractor';


@Component({
selector: 'app-home',
templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
})

@NgModule({
imports: [
CommonModule,
FormsModule,
IonicModule,
RouterModule.forChild([
  {
    path: '',
    component: HomePage
  }
])
],
declarations: [HomePage]
})

export class HomePageModule {
Usuário: string;
Senha: string;
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController){}

login(){
 console.log("Usuário: "+ this.Usuário);
 console.log("Senha: "+ this.Senha);

} 
}
```

Comment: Please don't use punctuation characters like `´` when naming variables (in any programming language) .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to define the `login()` function in your component class and not in your module. Please separate the module class and the component class into separate files. Your **home.page.ts** file should look like

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-home',
  templateUrl: 'home.page.html',
})
export class HomePage {
  Usuário: string;
  Senha: string;
  constructor(public navCtrl: NavController){}

  login(){
    console.log("Usuário: "+ this.Usuário);
    console.log("Senha: "+ this.Senha);
  } 
}
```

And the login function will execute properly. And your **home.module.ts** (or whatever you have named the module file) should look like

```js
@NgModule({
  imports: [
    CommonModule,
    FormsModule,
    IonicModule,
    RouterModule.forChild([
      { path: '', component: HomePage}
    ])
  ],
  declarations: [HomePage]
})
export class HomeModule {}
```

Comment: its okay but everything doing in css file doesn`t apear like panel size colors...

Comment: You have to define the `styleUrls` property pointing to the css file in the component decorator.